# Proof-like block with both start and end marks

Tags: amsthm, ntheorem, block

How can something like shown in the following picture be achieved?

[image: Example block]

I want to have a block (like the `proof` block in the `amsthm`/`ntheorem` packages) with both start and end marks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an new environment with arguments for that :

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{amssymb}

    \newenvironment{my_block}[2]
        {\noindent\textbf{#1} #2\newline%
        $\blacktriangleright$}
        {$\blacksquare$\par}

\begin{document}
    \begin{my_block}{Example.}{Example name}
        Example body
    \end{my_block}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Of course, if ***Example.*** is an argument you use in each environement, you can pass it into the environment definition and keep only one argument (cf. flav's answer).

Answer (score 1):

As a beginning :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage[geometry]{ifsym}

\newenvironment{bproof}[1]
{
  \noindent\textbf{Exmaple.} #1\\[5mm]  
  \FilledBigSquare
}
{
  \FilledBigTriangleRight 
}

\begin{document}

\begin{bproof}{Example name}
  Example Body.
\end{bproof}
\\
\begin{bproof}{Example name 2}
  Example Body.

  Example Body.
\end{bproof}

\end{document}
```

[image]